Adams Spectral Sequence - Computation of Sheaf Cohomology from a Cochain Complex
I'll start this question just like my last question and will hope that the problem resolves itself in the end (like it happened there).
I have little experience with algebraic geometry but it seems relevant to understand homotopy theory, so I'm grateful to any pointer on how to understand the following rigorously. Namely, I'm trying to understand the following result in Lurie's notes on chromatic homotopy theory.
Proposition 8.5(4). Let $\mathbb{G} = \operatorname{Spec}{\mathcal{A}^{\vee}}$ where $\mathcal{A}^{\vee}$ is the dual Steenrod algebra (for the prime $p = 2$) and $V = H_{\bullet}(X;\mathbb{F}_2)$ for any $X \in \mathsf{Sp}$. Then, $H^{b}(\mathbb{G}, H_{\bullet}(X;\mathbb{F}_2))$ is computed by the cohomology of the cochain complex
$$ V \to \Gamma(\mathbb{G}, V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{G}}) \to \Gamma(\mathbb{G}^2, V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{G}^2}) \to \cdots. $$
I probably don't understand the cohomology of sheaves/stacks/topoi well enough, but this somehow mildly looks like a derived functor or a Čech complex but also does not - I cannot find a way to make this work precisely.
To make this question accessible for non-homotopy theorists: Probably the explicit forms of $\mathbb{G}$ and $V$ are not so important. Probably an affine scheme $\mathbb{G}$ and a quasicoherent sheaf $V$ on $\mathbb{G}$ will also already work?
Unfortunately, the question did not resolve itself, so any help is appreciated!

This is group cohomology, not cohomology of $\mathbb G$ as a space. Compare first to cohomology of an ordinary (discrete, say) group $G$. This is very down-to-earth and is classically computed by a cochain complex that is essentially identical to your complex.
To view it as a Cech complex, group cohomology can also be computed as the cohomology of $*//G$, the classifying stack of $G$. This has a cover by $*$, and the Cech cohomology of this cover produces exactly the same complex. (See also the Galois cohomology of a field computed by the cover $\mathrm{Spec\ }k^{sep}\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec\ }k$).
In your case you have the same situation except with $\mathrm{Spec\ }\mathbb F_2//\mathbb G$ and the cover by $\mathrm {Spec}\ \mathbb F_2$.

Thanks, that's helpful! I wasn't familiar at all with group scheme cohomology, so I've written out some more details below.

I really am inexperienced with algebraic geometry! Slown's answer contains all that's happening but it still took me quite a while to understand it, as a few notions were not familiar to me. So I'm writing this answer to try to make this precise. The material I am a little familiar with is parts of Adeel Khan's notes on stacks and Nikolaus-Schreiber-Stevenson's paper on principal $\infty$-bundles, so I'm writing with them in mind.
Let $G = \operatorname{Spec}{A}$ be an affine group scheme and $V = \widetilde{M} \in \mathsf{Rep}(G) \simeq \mathsf{Comod}(A)$. Consider the cochain complex
$$ M \to M \otimes A \to M \otimes A \otimes A \to M \otimes A \otimes A \otimes A \to \cdots. $$
This is precisely the Hochschild complex $C^{\bullet}(G,V)$ and its cohomology is the group scheme cohomology $H^{\bullet}_{\mathrm{grp}}(G, V)$ (see Jantzen, p. 77).
On the other hand, we may consider the quotient stack $[*/G]$. By definition, $$[*/G](\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}}) = \operatorname{Map}(\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}}, BG) \simeq (G\text{-}\mathsf{Bund})(\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}}) \simeq \mathsf{Comod}(A), $$
so $V \in [*/G](\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{Z}})$. There is an fpqc cover $* \to [*/G]$ leading to a Čech nerve
$$ \cdots \to G \times G \times G \to G \times G \to G \to * $$
of $[*/G]$ (corresponding to the effective epimorphism $* \to [*/G]$) whose Čech complex has terms $$\check{C}^n(\{* \}, V) = M(G \times \cdots \times G) \cong M(\operatorname{Spec}(A \otimes \cdots \otimes A)) \cong M \otimes A \otimes \cdots \otimes A$$
so we return to the previous setting. Take Čech cohomology.
I personally wasn't familiar with group scheme cohomology and thus also could not know how the Čech cohomology of $[*/G]$ computes the group scheme cohomology of $G$. In Lurie's setting of chromatic homotopy theory, everything is the same, the only difference is that we work over $\operatorname{Spec}{\mathbb{F}_2}$. Incidentally, a similar observation is also used later on the same page of Lurie's text (namely $H^b(\mathbb{G}; H_{\bullet}(X;\mathbb{F}_2)) \cong H^b(Y/\mathbb{G}, \mathcal{O}_{Y/\mathbb{G}})$ in his notation).
